# Retrieve directory structure of FTP site with symbolic links

Tags: python, ftp, bioinformatics

I need to know the contents of the `latest_assembly_versions` directories for each species here:  ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria/

In other words, I need to `ls` every file matching this pattern:  `bacteria/*/latest_assembly_versions/GCA*` and write the results to a file.

I am going to use this information to organize the files, once I download them all, by replicating the way they have the files organized in the respective folders.

Something that might make this tricky is the fact that the files in the latest_assembly_versions directories are symbolic links.

Currently, I am running this for each species, but it is extremely inefficient, taking several hours to complete:

```
def get_latest_assembly_versions(genbank_mirror, species):

      latest_dir = os.path.join(species, "latest_assembly_versions")
      latest_assembly_versions = os.path.join(info_dir, "latest_assembly_versions.csv")
      try:
          complete_ids = [complete_id.split("/")[-1] for complete_id in ftp.nlst(latest_dir)]
          print(species, len(complete_ids))
          short_ids = ["_".join(accession_id.split("_")[:2]) for accession_id in complete_ids]
          complete_and_short = zip(complete_ids, short_ids)
          with open(latest_assembly_versions, "a") as f:
              for item in complete_and_short:
                  complete_id = item[0]
                  short_id = item[1]
                  f.write("{},{},{}\n".format(species, short_id, complete_id))
      except error_temp:
          continue
```

Suggestions greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: All you can do is to parallelize the processing.

Comment: I did that with SLURM, taking care to make sure I was not sending more than 3 requests per second as per NCBI's FTP rules, but it seems that ncbi.ftp is so inconsistent as to render that approach useless.  One day, all of my jobs will complete, returning the desired output, i.e. a mapping of each file to its appropriate directory, and the next day none of the jobs will complete, leaving with with ~1% of the information I need.